# CSS Static Play Button

Tags: html, css, button, playback

I'm trying to make a play button. I've run in to some trouble trying to get the play triangle to center in the circle. I've been trying to figure this out with no avail so I thought I'd ask you guys and gals!

If you have any other suggestions on how to do this I would love to know!

Thanks guys!

HTML:

```
    <a href="#">
      Learn more
      <br>
      <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
    </a>
```

CSS:

```
#play-btn{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 3px solid #FFF;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: .7;
}

#play-btn:hover{
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 500ms ease;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}

.fa-play{
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  color: #FFF;
  opacity: .7;
  font-size: 50px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.fa-play:hover{
  color: #FFF;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/grpzmr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually You just need to make minor modification with your CSS.

Just add the below CSS for the class #play-btn, and your problem will be resolved.

```
text-align:center;
padding-left: 10px;
```

Or Check it out below updated code :

HTML :

```
<a href="#">
      Learn more
      <br>
      <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
    </a>
```

CSS :

```
#play-btn{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 3px solid #FFF;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: .7;
  text-align:center;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#play-btn:hover{
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 500ms ease;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}

.fa-play{
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  color: #FFF;
  opacity: .7;
  font-size: 50px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.fa-play:hover{
  color: #FFF;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Just copy and paste and check it out i hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Just apply the `text-align:center;` in the `#play-btn` to center its contents:

```
#play-btn {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 3px solid #FFF;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: .7;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Your [updated pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dMoezb).